# How can we use std::array when the size of the array is given from the config file via command line arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to use `std::array` whose size is given by a config file via command line argument in C++.

The config looks like this

```
100 // array size
... // other application parameters
```

Even in a more simpler setting where the array size is expected to be determined via command line argument, i.e. `./main 100`, this wouldn't work since the array size is not determined at compile time.

```cpp
#include <array>                                                                                       

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  if (argc != 2)
    return 1;

  int n = stoi(argv[1]);

  std::array<int, n> arr;
  ... // do my job

}
```

Are there any hacks to do the same thing using `std::array`, not dynamic STL containers?

Comment: *not dynamic STL containers?* -- What is the issue with using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set of permissible values for `n` is known at compile-time (say, `1`, `10` or `100`), you can generate code for each of these values (this can lead to a code bloat, however) and then use `if`s to select the branch at run-time. With C++17 fold expressions this idea can be implemented in the following way:

```
template<std::size_t n>
void foo_impl(/* some parameters */) {
    std::array<int, n> arr;
    // ...
}

template<std::size_t... ns, typename... Args>
void foo(std::size_t n, Args&&... args) {
    assert(((n == ns) || ...));
    ((n == ns && (foo_impl<ns>(std::forward<Args>(args)...), true)), ...);
}

const std::size_t n = /* run-time value */;
foo<1, 10, 100>(n, /* some parameters */);
```

Here `n == ns && expr` is a well-known "hack" to evaluate `expr` only if the condition `n == ns` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: This may be the one I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

You need a dynamic container, if your dimensions are given at runtime. That's kind of the definition of dynamic!

If you are forbidden to use dynamic allocation, you will have to have a large `std::array`, with potentially many unused elements and a maximum supported upper bound for the figure in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

`std::array` requires you to know the size at compile time.
The only way to do what you say would be to have your program compile another program with the right size value and execute it.

Best option here is probably to use a dynamic size container like  `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any hacks to do the same thing using std::array, not dynamic STL containers?

No, there are no such hacks. It is only possible to use `std::array` with a compile time constant size.

If you want dynamic size, then you need to use a dynamic array (or some other dynamic data structure).

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to define an `std::array` length on runtime.
You could used `std::vector` instead.

It behaves (kind of) like an array, just it allocated the block for the memory within the heap.
Your could could then be like this:

```cpp
int n = stoi(argv[1]);
std::vector<int> my_data{};
my_data.resize(n); //Allocates n elements
```